# How can I use mod_rewrite to sub something for an accented character?

Tags: mod-rewrite, special-characters

I have a user that has sent out a QR Code to be printed, and the embedded URL includes an accented e (`é`) at the end. The link is to a wordpress site that sanitizes permalinks (by removing such things as accented characters) so I can't simply change the URL to include the `é` because wordpress won't let me. The result is that the URL with the `é` doesn't match the desired permalink that uses `e`, and a 404 results.

Is there a way for `mod_rewrite` to identify the errant `é` and change it to an `e`? In this particular case, the `é` will only ever occur at the end of the url, and will only ever need to be switched to an `e`, but a general case would be interesting to see.

What I have tried is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    # if a é is encountered at the end of a URL, switch it to an e
    RewriteRule ^(.+)[é] $1e [NE]
 </IfModule>
```

but no luck. I suspect this has to do with the fact that the `é` is not actually sent as `é` but as an encoded verion of `é` but I'm not sure.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that Apache is not actually seeing the charater as `é` but something else.  When I tried it, Apache actually the character was `Ã©`.

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule (.*)Ã© $1e
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @clmarquart. Unfortunately that didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this did the trick for me"

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)é(.*)$ /$1e$2 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks everyone!